# Set threshold for silence when using SpeechRecognitionEngine

Tags: c#, .net, speech-recognition

When using the [`SpeechRecognitionEngine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine?view=netframework-4.8) class in the `System.Speech.Recognition` namespace of the .NET framework, input that I would consider silence (a peak amplitude of roughly -30 dbFS or less in the audio from [`SpeechRecognizedEventArgs.Result.Audio`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.recognition.recognitionresult.audio?view=netframework-4.8#System_Speech_Recognition_RecognitionResult_Audio)) is often recognized as a phrase from the loaded grammar with high confidence (90% or greater).

Is it possible to set an amplitude/volume threshold below which input data will be ignored and/or considered to be silence? Silence during an ongoing recognition, e.g., the pauses between words, is fine, but recognition events should not be raised during periods when all the input data are below the amplitude threshold.

There are a few properties related to silence timeouts (`InitialSilenceTimeout`, `EndSilenceTimeout`, and `EndSilenceTimeoutAmbiguous`), but I've been unable to find anything related to defining the characteristics of silence itself.

Comment: If you're using the microphone, I would just adjust the input sensitivity in Windows. I don't think there are settings for this in the speech recognition engine.

Comment: It's my understanding that the audio data in `SpeechRecognizedEventArgs.Result.Audio` include any adjustments Windows has made, i.e., it's the input the recognition engine used. If the microphone sensitivity were set too high, I'd expect clipping, distortion, etc., not extremely low-amplitude audio data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [`RecognizedAudio.WriteToAudioStream()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.recognition.recognizedaudio.writetoaudiostream?view=netframework-4.8#System_Speech_Recognition_RecognizedAudio_WriteToAudioStream_System_IO_Stream_) to get the audio data associated with each recognition and performing a threshold check myself.

```
// Given a variable "args" of type System.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognizedEventArgs:
var stream = new MemoryStream();
args.Result.Audio.WriteToAudioStream(stream); // args.Result.Audio is of type RecognizedAudio.

// The RecognizedAudio documentation doesn't specify the format used by WriteToAudioStream.
// Inspection of the wave files produced by RecognizedAudio.WriteToWaveStream indicates they're 16-bit mono (at least on my machine).
// WriteToAudioStream writes the same data as WriteToWaveStream, just without the wave header.

byte[] bytes = stream.ToArray();
short[] samples = new short[bytes.Length / 2]; // Half the length because two bytes store one int16.
Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, samples, 0, bytes.Length);

// Check if peak amplitude exceeds a silence threshold. In my case:
// - Find the maximum absolute value in "samples".
// - Convert it to dBFS (20.0*Math.Log10(peak)).
// - Only react to recognition events with a peak in excess of -24 dBFS.
```